# Why does .net framework have different control heights?

Tags: .net, alignment, height, controls

Depending on the form's font I have:

- DateTimePicker height = 23
- ComboBox height = 26
- Label height = 18
- TextBox height = 23

I consider myself almost a "veteran" .net developer, but I still don't understand the reason for this model. What is the best approach to aligning/resizing these controls so that it looks professional if one wants to put them in one line? I could select all the controls and "Align Middles" but it just doesn't look alright.

Answer (score 0):

Just put them into `TableLayoutPanel` container and set `Anchor` value of each control, that you want to align, to "Left" (or "Left-Right"). Then you can move, resize, auto-size or dock whole container and all controls inside will remain aligned.

[image: Aligned controls]